# Qual è il senso di "sfregare sopra" in questo passaggio?

Tags: meaning, verbs

Nel racconto *Il signor Podestà*, di Beppe Fenoglio, ho letto:

> Ma per quanto ci **sfregasse sopra**, non riusciva a sentire un vero bruciore per quel tradimento. Era troppo assorbito e ricompensato dalla sua relazione benissimo avviata con Maria, l’unica figlia, minorenne, di Giovanni e Candida Cora, mezzadri nella cascina del veterinario.

Nei dizionari che ho consultato, ho visto che "sfregare" significa "fregare o strofinare una superficie" oppure "graffiare o urtare di striscio". Tuttavia, nel brano sopra citato, questo verbo sembra avere un senso figurato. Sapreste spiegarmi cosa significa?

Comment: Una zanzara ti punge, a intervalli sei cosciente della puntura ed allora ci sfreghi sopra ed allora ti brucia.  Lui invece no, a intervalli è cosciente di essere stato tradito e per un mondo di motivi (in primis la sua visione del mondo) ci sfrega sopra, eppure non brucia, non brucia veramente!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nel caso da te citato sfregare ha un senso figurato e significa rimuginare, ripensare.

Come nell'atto di sfregare tu passi più volte su uno stesso punto, alla stessa maniera, in senso figurato, per quanto pensasse e ripensasse al tradimento subìto, non riusciva a provare amarezza grazie soprattutto alla nuova relazione che era appena sbocciata.

Comment: Aggiungerei alla tua risposta che questo uso è completamente non standard; sembra un'invenzione dello scrittore.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni: Forse è in qualche modo correlato all'immagine di "sentire un bruciore" che penso abbia un uso figurato più comune.